# Expanding a dataframe using data.table

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

Consider a data frame of the form

```
       idnum      start        end var1 var2 var3 var4 
1993.1    17 1993-01-01 1993-12-31  foo  bar    1    2
```

with `start` and `end` being of type `Date`

```
 $ idnum : int  17 17 17 17 27 27
 $ start : Date, format: "1993-01-01" "1993-01-01" "1993-01-01" "1993-01-01" ...
 $ end   : Date, format: "1993-12-31" "1993-12-31" "1993-12-31" "1993-12-31" ...
```

I would like to create a *new* dataframe, that has instead monthly observations for every row, for every month in between `start` and `end` (including the boundaries):

**Desired Output**

```
idnum       month var1 var2 var3 var4 
   17  1993-01-01  foo  bar    1    2
   17  1993-02-01  foo  bar    1    2
...
   17  1993-12-01  foo  bar    1    2
```

I was [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24804211/1082349)

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.2+
setDT(df)[, list(idnum=idnum, month=seq(start,end,by="month")), by=1:nrow(df)]
```

However, I have a long list of additional columns that I also want to move with me (basically all the columns inside `df` besides `start`, `end`. Is there an elegant way of providing these additional columns? My naive approach was to replace idnum=idnum with colnames(df), which did not work.

**Update**

I tried, as suggested (since I wanted the code to be robust to changes of order in columns, I adjusted it slightly)

```
columnNames = colnames(df)[colnames(df) != 'start' & colnames(df) != 'end']
require(data.table) 
test <- data.frame(df)
setDT(test)
result <- test[, list( month=seq(start,end,by="month")), by=eval(columnNames) ]
```

but I got an

```
Error in seq.Date(start, end, by = "month") : 'from' must be of length 1
```

Comment: The problem here as I see it is that `data.table` doesn't know how exactly to expand your other variables, thus you'll need to set some type of rules

Comment: The other variables should just be copied among the expansion: `var1=var1, var2=var2,...`. I'm looking for a nice shorthand for that here.

Comment: Can you provide some more columns to your example data and the desired output?

Comment: I added some columns, I hope that removes confusion about my goals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the columns in `by=list(...)`

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.frame(idnum=17, 
                 start=as.Date("1993-01-01"), end=as.Date("1993-12-31"),
                 var1="foo",var2="bar",var3=1,var4=2)
setDT(df)
result <-df[,list(month=seq(start,end,by="month")), by=list(idnum,var1,var2,var3,var4)]
head(result)
#    idnum var1 var2 var3 var4      month
# 1:    17  foo  bar    1    2 1993-01-01
# 2:    17  foo  bar    1    2 1993-02-01
# 3:    17  foo  bar    1    2 1993-03-01
# 4:    17  foo  bar    1    2 1993-04-01
# 5:    17  foo  bar    1    2 1993-05-01
# 6:    17  foo  bar    1    2 1993-06-01
```

If you have a great many columns and don't want to enumerate them, this will include all columns except 2:3: (produces the same result above with this dataset).

```
result <-df[,list(month=seq(start,end,by="month")), by=eval(names(df)[-(2:3)])]
```

Comment: I tried running this on my dataset, but I got an error - I updated my question.

Comment: Can you upload your dataset somewhere and post a link in your question? Absent that, it looks like you may have duplicate rows; that is, for a given combination of everything but start and end, you have multiple rows.

Comment: Great call, there were duplicate rows.