# Interpolation/ Extrapolation in R

Tags: r, interpolation, distribution, extrapolation

I have a data sets where in which duration of days varies for the value column.

Start       End        Value  Days
24-03-2011  24-05-2011  398   60
25-05-2011  21-07-2011  275   56
22-07-2011  13-09-2011  389   52
14-09-2011  18-11-2011  482   64
19-11-2011  13-01-2012  514   54
14-01-2012  19-02-2012  330   35
20-02-2012  12-04-2012  519   51
13-04-2012  24-05-2012  361   40
25-05-2012  24-06-2012  202   29

What I need is Monthly data for value column like monthly distribution

Start       End       Value Days
01-03-2011  31-03-2011  ?   31
01-04-2011  30-04-2011  ?   30
01-05-2011  31-05-2011  ?   31
01-06-2011  30-06-2011  ?   30
01-07-2011  31-07-2011  ?   31
01-08-2011  31-08-2011  ?   31
01-09-2011  30-09-2011  ?   30
01-10-2011  31-10-2011  ?   31
01-11-2011  30-11-2011  ?   30
01-12-2011  31-12-2011  ?   31
01-01-2012  31-01-2012  ?   31
01-02-2012  29-02-2012  ?   29
01-03-2012  31-03-2012  ?   31
01-04-2012  30-04-2012  ?   30

I don't know if its Interpolation/Extrapolation problem But I have been suggested these method. Please Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can expand your data frame by day using the accepted solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24803361/expand-rows-by-date-range-using-start-and-end-date):

```
library(data.table)
df2 <- setDT(df)[, list(Value = Value, 
                        date = seq(from = Start, to = End, length.out = Days)), 
                 by = 1:nrow(df)]

> df2
     nrow Value       date
  1:    1   398 2011-03-24
  2:    1   398 2011-03-25
  3:    1   398 2011-03-26
  4:    1   398 2011-03-27
  5:    1   398 2011-03-28
 ---                      
750:   16   371 2013-04-11
751:   16   371 2013-04-12
752:   16   371 2013-04-13
753:   16   371 2013-04-14
754:   16   371 2013-04-16
```

Assuming you want to distribute each value in the original data frame evenly across all the days from start to end, you can then do this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df2 %>%

  # calculate average for each day
  group_by(nrow) %>%
  mutate(Value = Value / n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%

  # summarize by month
  mutate(Month = format(date, "%Y-%m")) %>%
  group_by(Month) %>%
  summarise(Value = sum(Value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%

  # derive start / end dates for each month
  mutate(Start = ymd(paste0(Month, "-1"))) %>%
  mutate(End = Start %m+% months(1) - 1) %>% 
  mutate(Days = End - Start + 1) %>% 
  select(Start, End, Value, Days) 

# A tibble: 26 x 4
        Start        End     Value    Days
       <date>     <date>     <dbl>  <time>
 1 2011-03-01 2011-03-31  53.06667 31 days
 2 2011-04-01 2011-04-30 192.36667 30 days
 3 2011-05-01 2011-05-31 186.94167 31 days
 4 2011-06-01 2011-06-30 142.41071 30 days
 5 2011-07-01 2011-07-31 173.02198 31 days
 6 2011-08-01 2011-08-31 224.42308 31 days
 7 2011-09-01 2011-09-30 217.80048 30 days
 8 2011-10-01 2011-10-31 225.93750 31 days
 9 2011-11-01 2011-11-30 242.25347 30 days
10 2011-12-01 2011-12-31 285.55556 31 days
# ... with 16 more rows
```

Data:

```
df <- read.table(
  header = T,
  stringsAsFactors = F, 
  text = "Start       End        Value  Days
24-03-2011  24-05-2011  398   60
25-05-2011  21-07-2011  275   56
22-07-2011  13-09-2011  389   52
14-09-2011  18-11-2011  482   64
19-11-2011  13-01-2012  514   54
14-01-2012  19-02-2012  330   35
20-02-2012  12-04-2012  519   51
13-04-2012  24-05-2012  361   40
25-05-2012  24-06-2012  202   29
25-05-2012  06-08-2012  691   72
07-08-2012  23-09-2012  376   46
24-09-2012  06-11-2012  300   42
07-11-2012  21-12-2012  272   43
22-12-2012  31-01-2013  276   39
01-02-2013  02-03-2013  188   28
03-03-2013  16-04-2013  371   43"
)

df$Start = as.Date(df$Start, "%d-%m-%Y")
df$End = as.Date(df$End, "%d-%m-%Y")
```

Comment: Thank you so much Z.Lin. That's what I was looking for. I was stuck at this problem for quite a long time.