# Calculate column based on date logic between two tables

Tags: r, dplyr

I´d like to calculate a column based on a logic between tables. Let me explain, given a data.frame with this structure:

```
Transaction - Start - End - Quantity - Area
(Number) - (Date) - (Date) - (Number) - (Number)
```

`Start` and `End` determine how long has a `Transaction` been in an `Area`. I want to calculate the *stock* in each `Area` for *each day*.

What is stock?
The sum of Quantity that follows this logic:

```
Start <= day AND End >= day
OR
Start <= day AND End == NULL
```

What is day? Each day of the calendar. (Thus the *logic between tables*.)

How can the stock per day per area be calculated in R? Example data:

```
calendar <- as.data.frame(seq.Date(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2019-01-10"), 1))
colnames(calendar) <- c("Date")

> head(calendar)
        Date
1 2019-01-01
2 2019-01-02
3 2019-01-03
4 2019-01-04
5 2019-01-05
6 2019-01-06

Transaction <- c(299784, 299785, 301913, 302840, 305722, 285874, 285875, 312587, 326842, 328521)
Start <- as.Date(c("2019-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-03", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-03"))
End <- as.Date(c("2019-01-05", "2019-01-04", "2019-01-06", "2019-01-03", "NULL", "2019-01-05", "2019-01-04", "2019-01-06", "2019-01-03", "NULL"))
Quantity <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
Area <- c(7065, 7065, 7065, 7065, 7065, 6098, 6098, 6098, 6098, 6098)
df <- data.frame(Transaction, Start, End, Quantity, Area)

> df
   Transaction      Start        End Quantity Area
1       299784 2019-01-01 2019-01-05        1 7065
2       299785 2019-01-01 2019-01-04        1 7065
3       301913 2019-01-02 2019-01-06        1 7065
4       302840 2019-01-02 2019-01-03        1 7065
5       305722 2019-01-03       <NA>        1 7065
6       285874 2019-01-01 2019-01-05        1 6098
7       285875 2019-01-01 2019-01-04        1 6098
8       312587 2019-01-02 2019-01-06        1 6098
9       326842 2019-01-02 2019-01-03        1 6098
10      328521 2019-01-03       <NA>        1 6098
```

The stock each day would be:

```
         Date  Area Stock
1  2019-01-01  7065     2
2  2019-01-02  7065     4
3  2019-01-03  7065     5
4  2019-01-04  7065     4
5  2019-01-05  7065     3
6  2019-01-06  7065     2
7  2019-01-07  7065     1
8  2019-01-08  7065     1
9  2019-01-09  7065     1
10 2019-01-10  7065     1
11 2019-01-01  6098     2
12 2019-01-02  6098     4
13 2019-01-03  6098     5
14 2019-01-04  6098     4
15 2019-01-05  6098     3
16 2019-01-06  6098     2
17 2019-01-07  6098     1
18 2019-01-08  6098     1
19 2019-01-09  6098     1
20 2019-01-10  6098     1
```

or:

```
         Date  7065  6098
1  2019-01-01     2     2
2  2019-01-02     4     4
3  2019-01-03     5     5
4  2019-01-04     4     4
5  2019-01-05     3     3
6  2019-01-06     1     1
7  2019-01-07     1     1
8  2019-01-08     1     1
9  2019-01-09     1     1
10 2019-01-10     1     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit3**:

This approach has the following principle:
You need to calculate per day your stock but you have a range of days. We have to thus *convert the range of days to single days*, while maintaining the rest of the data, and then group and count as below.
However you have the 'annoying' **NAs** in there, thus we have to first get rid of those. Since when the **End** Date is **NA**, you want to still consider the transaction as ongoing, first i'd *convert the **NAs** as the maximum date of your calendar dataframe*, so we'll count them later on as 1 for each day till max:

```
df$End <- as.Date(ifelse(is.na(df$End), max(calendar$Date), df$End), origin = "1970-01-01")
> df
   Transaction      Start        End Quantity Area
1       299784 2019-01-01 2019-01-05        1 7065
2       299785 2019-01-01 2019-01-04        1 7065
3       301913 2019-01-02 2019-01-06        1 7065
4       302840 2019-01-02 2019-01-03        1 7065
5       305722 2019-01-03 2019-01-10        1 7065
6       285874 2019-01-01 2019-01-05        1 6098
7       285875 2019-01-01 2019-01-04        1 6098
8       312587 2019-01-02 2019-01-06        1 6098
9       326842 2019-01-02 2019-01-03        1 6098
10      328521 2019-01-03 2019-01-10        1 6098
```

After this we need to generate the missing dates, between the **Start**-**End** dates. To do so we can use `complete` from `tidyr` as per [MKR's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49348045/7856717), in the following way:

```
library(tidyr)
nf <- df %>% group_by(row_number()) %>% complete(Start=seq.Date(max(Start), max(End), by='day')) %>% fill(Transaction, End, Quantity, Area)
```

Our new dataframe **nf** now has a new **Start** date that corresponds to each Transaction/Quantity/Area combination *unique* for the date ranges.

```
> nf
# A tibble: 48 x 6
# Groups:   row_number() [10]
   `row_number()` Start      Transaction End        Quantity  Area
            <int> <date>           <dbl> <date>        <dbl> <dbl>
 1              1 2019-01-01      299784 2019-01-05        1  7065
 2              1 2019-01-02      299784 2019-01-05        1  7065
 3              1 2019-01-03      299784 2019-01-05        1  7065
 4              1 2019-01-04      299784 2019-01-05        1  7065
 5              1 2019-01-05      299784 2019-01-05        1  7065
 6              2 2019-01-01      299785 2019-01-04        1  7065
 7              2 2019-01-02      299785 2019-01-04        1  7065
 8              2 2019-01-03      299785 2019-01-04        1  7065
 9              2 2019-01-04      299785 2019-01-04        1  7065
10              3 2019-01-02      301913 2019-01-06        1  7065
# … with 38 more rows
```

We can then proceed with what I already suggested earlier:

```
zf <- nf %>% group_by(Start, Area) %>% tally(Quantity)

> zf
# A tibble: 20 x 3
# Groups:   Start [10]
   Start       Area     n
   <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
 1 2019-01-01  6098     2
 2 2019-01-01  7065     2
 3 2019-01-02  6098     4
 4 2019-01-02  7065     4
 5 2019-01-03  6098     5
 6 2019-01-03  7065     5
 7 2019-01-04  6098     4
 8 2019-01-04  7065     4
 9 2019-01-05  6098     3
10 2019-01-05  7065     3
11 2019-01-06  6098     2
12 2019-01-06  7065     2
13 2019-01-07  6098     1
14 2019-01-07  7065     1
15 2019-01-08  6098     1
16 2019-01-08  7065     1
17 2019-01-09  6098     1
18 2019-01-09  7065     1
19 2019-01-10  6098     1
20 2019-01-10  7065     1
```

What we are doing here, is we are asking `dplyr` to use the **Start** (which ended up being our unique transaction for that date) and the **Area** variables to give you the total of Quantities. You can then store this in a new table, in this example **zf**.

**Edit1:**
To end-up with your requested table format you can then run `spread` from the `tidyr` package

```
zf <-  zf %>% spread(Area, n)
>zf
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   Start [10]
   Start      `6098` `7065`
   <date>      <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 2019-01-01      2      2
 2 2019-01-02      4      4
 3 2019-01-03      5      5
 4 2019-01-04      4      4
 5 2019-01-05      3      3
 6 2019-01-06      2      2
 7 2019-01-07      1      1
 8 2019-01-08      1      1
 9 2019-01-09      1      1
10 2019-01-10      1      1
```

This spreads the column **Area** on new columns based on your counts (**n**).
Finally all you have to do is keep the dates that exist in your **calendar** dataframe.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The End date is relevant. For example, the 8th of January there is a stock of 1 for Area 7065 because there is a transaction open (5th row of 'df'), meaning, 2018-01-03 <= 2018-01-08 and End == null. For the 2nd of January there is a stock of 4 for Area 7065 (accounting for the 2º, 3º, 4º and 5º row of 'df').

Comment: I see your point now - i misunderstood the complexity then. I will get back to you.

Comment: Questions: On your calendar you have 2019 dataframe you have 2019 and on your df you have 2018. Is this a typo? Otherwise all the days will be > than your df$End. I am editing my response currently to reflect your comments.

Comment: Check my edited response, let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help Steve, that definitely works. The only caveat is that populating the missing dates makes the table much bigger (imagine a production table like this where a transaction has an average lead time of 60 days, the table would increase its size by 60!) However I think I can manage that with careful filtering of the data. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helps! I made a mistake in the grouping by the way: You need to use `tally(Quantity)` instead of `count()` since we want the sum of Quantity and not just the number of dates appearing. I made a final edit. Good luck and keep up the good work!