# Apply seq.Date using two dataframe columns

Tags: r, date, sequence

I tried to use the varies answers from
[Expanding a sequence in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494511/expanding-a-sequence-in-a-data-frame)
to my dataframe, but nothing I tried works.

Sample Data

```
library(dplyr)    
p1 <- c(1:5)
p2 <- as.Date(c("2013-01-01","2013-01-22","2014-02-01","2014-05-12","2015-02-22"))
p3 <- as.Date(c("2013-01-11","2013-01-30","2014-02-20","2014-05-22","2015-02-28"))
p4 <- c(11,9,20,11,7)
df2 <- data_frame(p1,p2,p3,p4)
names(df2) <- c("ID", "StartDate", "EndDate", "NoDays")
df2
```

Desired Result

```
ID  datelist    NoDays
1   2013-01-01   1
1   2013-01-02   1 
1   2013-01-03   1
etc..
1   2013-01-10   1
1   2013-01-11   1
2   2013-01-22   1
2   2013-01-23   1
etc.
2   2013-01-28   1
2   2013-01-29   1
2   2013-01-30   1
```

Here are three code trials - all of which I tried in numerous variants (e.g. verious members of the apply family), but all failed (i.e. giving diverse error messages):

code example 1

```
datelist <- seq.Date(from = df2$StartDate, to=df2$StartDate, by="days")
```

code example 2

```
datelist <- seq.Date(from = df2$StartDate, by="days", length.out = df2$NoDays)
```

code example 2

```
datelist <- apply(df2, 1, seq.Date(from = df2$StartDate, to=df2$StartDate, by="days"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you give a vector to `seq.Date` which takes a unique value as `from` or `to`.

On the same idea as your apply call it should be:

```
apply(df2,1,function(x) { seq.Date( as.Date(x['StartDate']), as.Date(x['EndDate']), by='days') } )
```

Which gives you a list with each row sequence:

```
[[1]]
 [1] "2013-01-01" "2013-01-02" "2013-01-03" "2013-01-04" "2013-01-05" "2013-01-06" "2013-01-07" "2013-01-08" "2013-01-09"
[10] "2013-01-10" "2013-01-11"

[[2]]
[1] "2013-01-22" "2013-01-23" "2013-01-24" "2013-01-25" "2013-01-26" "2013-01-27" "2013-01-28" "2013-01-29" "2013-01-30"

[[3]]
 [1] "2014-02-01" "2014-02-02" "2014-02-03" "2014-02-04" "2014-02-05" "2014-02-06" "2014-02-07" "2014-02-08" "2014-02-09"
[10] "2014-02-10" "2014-02-11" "2014-02-12" "2014-02-13" "2014-02-14" "2014-02-15" "2014-02-16" "2014-02-17" "2014-02-18"
[19] "2014-02-19" "2014-02-20"

[[4]]
 [1] "2014-05-12" "2014-05-13" "2014-05-14" "2014-05-15" "2014-05-16" "2014-05-17" "2014-05-18" "2014-05-19" "2014-05-20"
[10] "2014-05-21" "2014-05-22"

[[5]]
[1] "2015-02-22" "2015-02-23" "2015-02-24" "2015-02-25" "2015-02-26" "2015-02-27" "2015-02-28"
```

To get your desired output, we should return id and NoDays columns too.

In base R I would do it like this:

```
getDfForDates <- function(row) {
  dseq <- seq.Date( as.Date(row['StartDate']), as.Date(row['EndDate']), by='days')
  data.frame( ID=row['ID'], datelist=dseq, NoDays=1)
}

rbindlist(
  apply(df2,1,function(x) { 
    getDfForDates(x)
  } )
)
```

Another solution with `data.table` package is:

```
setDT(df2)
df2[, list(datelist=seq.Date( StartDate, EndDate, by='days'), NoDays=1), by=ID]
```

Both will give desired result if I didn't miss a point.

<strike>I'll see if I can craft a correct dplyr answer as you seems to be using this package.</strike> Finally found a dupe when looking for dplyr examples, voted to close.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I use dplyr because I know it best, but i am always open to learn new packages. Thanks a lot again for your help!

Comment: @user2006697 You're welcome, see akrun answer and the duplicate for dplyr syntax. He's far better than me :p

Comment: @Tensibai  I think you know a lot more about other languages.  So, I might be lagging behind you.

Answer (score 4):

We can do this easily with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df2)`, if the 'ID's are unique, then group by 'ID', and get the `seq` of 'StartDate' to 'EndDate' `by` 'ID'.

```
library(data.table)
res <- setDT(df2)[,list(datelist=seq(StartDate, EndDate, by='1 day'), 
                      NoDays = 1) , by = ID]

head(res)
#   ID   datelist NoDays
#1:  1 2013-01-01      1
#2:  1 2013-01-02      1
#3:  1 2013-01-03      1
#4:  1 2013-01-04      1
#5:  1 2013-01-05      1
#6:  1 2013-01-06      1
```

---

If we need to do this in `dplyr`, we may need the `do` as `mutate` doesn't support this kind of operations

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>% 
   rowwise() %>%
   do(data.frame(ID= .$ID, datelist = seq(.$StartDate, 
             .$EndDate, by = '1 day'), NoDays= 1))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot!. What if NoDays cannot be fixed but has to be calculated? E.g. like "NoDays / datdiff(StartDate,EndDate)"? Can this be done with the data.table approach?

Comment: @user2006697 Yes, it can be calculated.  Just do the difference of `StartDate` and 'EndDate` by the 'ID'

Comment: Super - worked at once. Thanks million!