# generate rows for each id by date sequence

Tags: r, dataframe, row, sequence

my dataframe looks someway like this

```
df <- read.table(text="
                 id          start           end
    1            2      2018-10-01    2018-12-01
    2            3      2018-01-01    2018-04-01
", header=TRUE)
```

What I trying to achieve is get difference between start and day in months for each id and then generate new dataframe with each month for particular id. Result should be

```
result <- read.table(text="
                 id          date           
    1            2      2018-10-01
    2            2      2018-11-01
    3            2      2018-12-01     
    4            3      2018-01-01
    5            3      2018-02-01    
    6            3      2018-03-01    
    7            3      2018-04-01        
", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Related: [Expand ranges defined by “from” and “to” columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494511/expand-ranges-defined-by-from-and-to-columns), but it doesn't cover the `by = month` aspect in `seq`.

Answer (score 3):

Most straightforward way using base R functions is to create a `seq`uence of monthly dates for each row, create a dataframe and `rbind` them together

```
do.call(rbind, with(df,lapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) 
   data.frame(id = id[i], date = seq(as.Date(start[i]), as.Date(end[i]), by = "month")))))

#  id       date
#1  2 2018-10-01
#2  2 2018-11-01
#3  2 2018-12-01
#4  3 2018-01-01
#5  3 2018-02-01
#6  3 2018-03-01
#7  3 2018-04-01
```

Answer (score 3):

We can do this easily with `Map`. Pass the `Date` converted 'start' and 'end' columnd of the dataset as arguments to `Map`, get the sequence of 'month's as a `list` and expand the 'id' based on the `lengths` of `list` as well as concatenate the `list` elements to create the expanded dataframe

```
lst1 <- Map(seq, MoreArgs = list(by = 'month'), as.Date(df$start), as.Date(df$end))
data.frame(id = rep(df$id, lengths(lst1)), date = do.call(c, lst1))
#  id       date
#1  2 2018-10-01
#2  2 2018-11-01
#3  2 2018-12-01
#4  3 2018-01-01
#5  3 2018-02-01
#6  3 2018-03-01
#7  3 2018-04-01
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`, we `mutate` the `class` of the 'start', 'end' columns to `Date`, using `map2` (from `purrr`), get the `seq`uence of dates from 'start' to 'end' `by` the 'month' and expand the data by `unnest`ing the dataset

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate_at(2:3, as.Date) %>% 
  transmute(id = id, date = map2(start, end,  ~ seq(.x, .y, by = 'month'))) %>% 
  unnest
#  id       date
#1  2 2018-10-01
#2  2 2018-11-01
#3  2 2018-12-01
#4  3 2018-01-01
#5  3 2018-02-01
#6  3 2018-03-01
#7  3 2018-04-01
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with `purrr 0.2.5` and `dplyr 0.7.6`

Comment: Try it on a fresh session in case there are some function masking

Comment: Not sure what was wrong. Worked on Mac now but I had issue yesterday on Windows.

Comment: I am also using Mac.  So, it could be some issue in windows