# Fixing the error associated with creating a sequence of dates between start date and end date in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

***NOTE: please do not link a similar post. I have found several other similar postings, but their responses have not resolved the errors I get: "Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number" or "from must be of length 1".... I'm looking to understand why these error statements occur and how to prevent them from occuring... Thanks!

I have a data frame like the following

```
    id  startdate  enddate
    1   01/01/2011 01/05/2011
    1   02/03/2012 02/05/2012
    2   03/04/2013 03/06/2013
    3   04/06/2014 04/09/2014
```

I want to transform the data frame so as to create the following:

```
    id   date
    1    01/01/2011
    1    01/02/2011
    1    01/03/2011
    1    01/04/2011
    1    01/05/2011
    1    02/03/2012
    1    02/04/2012
    1    02/05/2012
    2    03/04/2013
    2    03/05/2013
    2    03/06/2013
```

.... and so on to fill in the sequence of dates between startdate and enddate

I have tried the following....

```
one<-as.data.table(one)
one[, startdate:=as.character(startdate)]
one[, enddate:=as.character(enddate)]
one[, startdate:=as.Date(startdate, format="%m/%d/%Y")]
one[, enddate:=as.Date(enddate, format="%m/%d/%Y")]
one<-as.data.frame(one)
one%>%
  rowwise() %>%
  do(data.frame(id=.$id, date=seq(.$startdate,.$enddate,by="day")))
```

When I run this, I get the following error: Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number

Why is this? And how can I fix this piece of code?

Comment: Your example doesn't show such a condition

Comment: Can you also check whether the dates format is same  or if there are multiple formats.  i.e. `seq(NA, Sys.Date(), by = '1 day')#
Error in seq.default(NA, Sys.Date(), by = "1 day") : 
  'from' must be a finite number`

Comment: Can you check whether the `anydate` update shows the same error

Comment: @akrun I just tried the anydate update and received the same error statement...thanks for all of your help and advice!!

Comment: If you can share a link to the data or a small example that shows the error, would dbe helpful

Comment: @akrun I ended up removing the observations where the start date and the end date were the same and your original solutions worked. Thanks!!

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494511/expand-ranges-defined-by-from-and-to-columns Isn't it similar? Does it give you what you want after you change the dates to standard format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `data.table`, we can use `Map`.  Convert the 'startdate' 'enddate' to `Date` class, use `Map` to get the `seq`uence of corresponding elements, `rep`licate the 'id' based on the `lengths` of the `list` output of dates, concatenate the `list` of dates to create the two column output

```
library(data.table)
one[, {lst1 <- Map(seq, as.IDate(startdate, "%m/%d/%Y"),
                       as.IDate(enddate, "%m/%d/%Y"),
                      MoreArgs = list(by = "day"))
         .(id = rep(id, lengths(lst1)), date = do.call(c, lst1))}]
#    id       date
# 1:  1 2011-01-01
# 2:  1 2011-01-02
# 3:  1 2011-01-03
# 4:  1 2011-01-04
# 5:  1 2011-01-05
# 6:  1 2012-02-03
# 7:  1 2012-02-04
# 8:  1 2012-02-05
# 9:  2 2013-03-04
#10:  2 2013-03-05
#11:  2 2013-03-06
#12:  3 2014-04-06
#13:  3 2014-04-07
#14:  3 2014-04-08
#15:  3 2014-04-09
```

---

If there are multiple formats in 'date' columns, one option is `anydate` from `anytime` to automatically convert some of the formats to `Date` class

```
library(anytime)
one[, {lst1 <- Map(seq, anydate(startdate),
                    anydate(enddate),
                   MoreArgs = list(by = "day"))
      .(id = rep(id, lengths(lst1)), date = do.call(c, lst1))}]
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
one %>% 
   transmute(id, date = map2(mdy(startdate), mdy(enddate), seq, by = 'day')) %>% 
   unnest(c(date))
# A tibble: 15 x 2
#     id date      
#   <int> <date>    
# 1     1 2011-01-01
# 2     1 2011-01-02
# 3     1 2011-01-03
# 4     1 2011-01-04
# 5     1 2011-01-05
# 6     1 2012-02-03
# 7     1 2012-02-04
# 8     1 2012-02-05
# 9     2 2013-03-04
#10     2 2013-03-05
#11     2 2013-03-06
#12     3 2014-04-06
#13     3 2014-04-07
#14     3 2014-04-08
#15     3 2014-04-09
```

#### data

```
one <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L), startdate = c("01/01/2011", 
"02/03/2012", "03/04/2013", "04/06/2014"), enddate = c("01/05/2011", 
"02/05/2012", "03/06/2013", "04/09/2014")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

setDT(one)
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error, of needing from to be a finite number

Comment: @boodaloo1 I showed a reprodducible example with the `data`.  Couldn't reproduce the issue

Comment: @boodaloo1 May be you have some 'enddate' less than the `startdate` in the original dataset

Comment: I only posted a few lines of my frame as it has a few thousand observations to it. I will check to see if the enddate is less than the startdate in any of the scenarios...thanks for the help!

Comment: @boodaloo1 that error wouldd be a different one.  I am thinking that the sspecific error is because some of the elements are iin a. different format, so when `as.Date` is applied, it returns NA and this created the `finite` error

Comment: they seem to be in the same format.... I did just find a few instances where startdate and enddate are the same. Could this create an issue?

Comment: It wouldn't be an issue `seq(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date(), by = '1 day')#
[1] "2020-02-10"`

Comment: @boodaloo1 Can you show a link to the data which shows the error