# How to duplicate a specific number of row per group level in R

Tags: r

[Here is my data:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGDU5.png)

For each x1 level, I am trying to duplicate a number of rows equal to number.class and I would like for each row the length class to goes from the Lmin..cm. to Lmax..cm. increasing by 1 for each row.I came up with this code:

```
test<-A.M %>% filter(x1=="Crenimugil crenilabis")
for (i in 1:test$number.class){test<-test %>%  add_row()}
for (i in 1:nrow(test)){test[i,]=test[1,]}
  for (i in 1:nrow(test)){test$length.class[i]<-print(i+test$Lmin..cm.)}
  test$length.class<-test$length.class-1
```

which basically works and gives me the expected results: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrPgn.png)

However, this script does not allow me to run this for every species.

Thank you.

Comment: Please use `dput` to show  a small example instead of images

Comment: This post might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494511/expand-ranges-defined-by-from-and-to-columns?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, we could use `uncount` from `tidyr` to replicate the rows, do a group by 'x1' and `mutate` the 'Lmin..cm' by adding the `row_number()`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
A.M %>%
    uncount(number.class) %>%
    group_by(x1) %>%
    mutate(`Lmin..cm.` = `Lmin..cm.` + row_number())
```

---

If we need to create a sequence from `Lmin..cm` to `Lmax..cm`, then instead of `uncount`, we could use `map2` to create the `seq`uence and then `unnest`

```
library(purrr)
A.M %>%
     mutate(new = map2(`Lmin..cm.`, `Lmax..cm`, ~ seq(.x, .y, by = 1)) %>%
    unnest(c(new))
```