# Reordering a dataframe in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, bioinformatics

I think this will be an easy question, but i could not find the answer until now. I have a dataframe with a start of a position and an end of a position like this:

```
name <- c("pr1", "pr1", "pr3")
start <- c(1,7,10)
end <- c(5,8,15)
ds <- cbind(name,start,end)
g <- as.data.frame(ds)
print(g)
```

Now, i want to have all positions from start to the end into a new data frame with each position named by the according name. Like this:

```
name  position
pr1   1
pr1   2
pr1   3
pr1   4
pr1   5
pr2   7
pr2   8
pr3   10
pr3   11
...  ...
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? Sorry if this has been asked before, I am new here :`D

Thanks alot!

EDIT: Answer can be found here: [Expand ranges defined by "from" and "to" columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494511/expand-ranges-defined-by-from-and-to-columns)

Comment: Using `tidyverse` : `g %>% mutate(position = map2(start, end, seq)) %>%unnest(position) %>% select(name, position)`

Comment: thanks alot, i found another answere here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494511/expand-ranges-defined-by-from-and-to-columns