# Problems creating nested data or better solution in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I want to create create an extra column with positions in a data frame. My plan was to use the start and end column as the input of `seq` command and expected with `as.list` to get a nested data entry which I can afterwards just `unnest`. But this is giving me an error.
So as n example:

```
tibble(
  start=c(1,7),
  end=c(3,10),
  total=15,
  value=c(100,200)
)
```

My expected result would be something like this:

```
tibble(
  start=c(1,1,1,7,7,7,7),
  end=c(3,3,3,10,10,10,10),
  total=15,
  value=c(100,100,100,200,200,200,200),
  position=c(1,2,3,7,8,9,10)
)
```

I tried something like

```
tibble(
  start=c(1,7),
  end=c(3,10),
  total=15,
  value=c(100,200)
) %>% 
  mutate(position=as.list(seq(start,end))) %>% 
  unnest(position)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Related: [Expand ranges defined by "from" and "to" columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494511/expand-ranges-defined-by-from-and-to-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from `seq`. You must apply your function row-wise, since the call is interpreting `seq(c(1, 7), c(3, 10))` by default.

To do that, you can use `mapply`, `pmap`, or `rowwise`.

```r
tbl %>% 
  mutate(position = mapply(seq, start, end))
```

```r
tbl %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(position = list(seq(start, end)))
```

Comment: Just for completeness, could you provide a solution using `rowwise`

Comment: Thanks! Just figured out, that in the rowwise solution I have to wrap in list... The rowwise solution is more intuitive I think. Thanks, that did the trick!